# How can I take a string and differentiate it in different strings each one with 2 characters?

Tags: c, poker

I was trying to do a program that analyzes poker hands, however I am extremely confused and I don't know where to start. The suits are represented by the letters `C`(clubs), `D`(diamonds), `H`(hearts) and `S`(spades).

The value of the cards is represented by the numbers and the letters `A`(ace), `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `T`(ten), `J`(jack), `Q`(queen) and `K`(king).

The program is supposed to receive input like `AS KC QC JH 9D`.

But the difficult part is that it should be able to receive 5, 7, 9 or 10 cards (strings with 2 chars).

Note: each card is made of two chars (example: `2C`).
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Do you have any code written already, or are you asking for a solution with a complete program?

Comment: I don't have anything, I don't even know where to start

Comment: Do you have any programming experience in any computer language?

Comment: I know a little of C, but I don't know how to take the input and differentiate the cards (strings of 2 chars). Especially because you can input 5, 7, 9 and 10 cards.

Comment: A card should be represented as a `struct` with a suit (0 to 3) and a value (2 to 14). The input can be stored in an array of those structs. And the first task in the code is to convert the letters to numbers, e.g. T=10, J=11, etc. and S=0, H=1, etc.

Comment: Is each hand (set of _n_ cards) passed in as a single string of 2*_n_ characters?

Comment: Yes with a space in between cards

Comment: I'd start with [`getline`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will offer incremental suggestions in this answer:

1. To determine how many cards are in the hand/set: you can call `strlen(string)` to count the number of characters in the string.
2. Once you know how many cards are there, you can use a `switch` statement: `switch(number_of_cards) { ... }` to branch the processing logic into distinct `case`s.